# Show fixed table with foreach function using PHP with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, tabular

I am using CodeIgniter and I have tables [which have **fixed data** on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLmDf.png) and I have to fill 1-12 with data in the database using PHP:

[image]

Could anyone help me about how to call the data from the database?

Comment: I think your question is about fetching data from database. May I have your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the solution:

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-xldj{border-color:inherit;text-align:left}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
```

**Html and PHP:**

```
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-xldj">Name</th>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Class</th>
        <th class="tg-0pky">Subject</th>
        <th class="tg-xldj">Date</th>
        <th class="tg-xldj">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-0pky">N1</td>
        <?php for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) { ?>
            <td class="tg-0pky"><?=$i?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-xldj">N2</td>
        <?php for($i=5;$i<=8;$i++) { ?>
            <td class="tg-0pky"><?=$i?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-0pky">N3</td>
        <?php for($i=9;$i<=12;$i++) { ?>
            <td class="tg-0pky"><?=$i?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```